# Linear Regression done simultaneously vs in parts

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

So I have a factor model which looks like:

$x_{i}(t)=\beta_{i0}F_{0}(t)+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\beta_{in}F_{n}(t) + \epsilon_{i}(t)$

I know that $F_{0}(t)$ is linearly orthogonal/uncorrelated to $F_{n}(t)$ for all $n$. Is there a difference between

1) Regressing $x_{i}(t)$ against $F_{0}(t)$ and then using the residue from this, $w_{i}(t)$, to find $\beta_{in}$ by regressing $w_{i}(t)$ against all $F_{n}(t)$ simultaneously (I use elastic net for the second regression)?

2) Regressing $x_{i}(t)$ against both $F_{0}(t)$ and all $F_{n}(t)$ simultaneously?

EDIT: So by uncorrelated I meant that the underlying factors $F_{0}(t)$ and $F_{n}(t)$ are uncorrelated. Hopefully this helps?

Comment: Do you mean that the sample observations of $F_0(t)$ are uncorrelated with those of $F_n(t)$ for all $n$, in the sense that the sample correlation coefficients are all equal to $0$, or that the underlying factor is uncorrelated, or both?

Comment: On what dimensions are you asking if there is a difference?

Comment: @jbowman - the underlying factors are uncorrelated i.e. $corr(F_{0}(t)(t),F_{n}(t))=0$ for all n.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Well I didn't realise there would be difference according to the dimension, but the number of factors n=1,2,...,26.